# How do I make my dataTable sorted if the data is ACTIVE or INACTIVE using JQuery and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My goal is that I want to sort my data if it is still ACTIVE or INACTIVE. But the result I've got is that if I click active it only shows the active data and when inactive it doesn't show. I don't have syntax errors but logical errors. I am using PHP, JQuery/AJAX.

Here is my code in HTML

```
    <?php 
    include('../include/header_ps.php');
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header"> Table of Tools Specification
                    <a href="../forms/form_toolspec.php">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                            <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>
                            Add Record
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- Status -->
        <div>

            <form action="GET">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Table group by Status </label>
                    <select name="selector_id" style="width:200px;" class="show-menu-arrow form-control" id="stats" required>
                        <option value="1" id="active" selected=""> ACTIVE </option>
                        <option value="0" id="inactive"> INACTIVE </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Table of Tools Specification
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th> Tools Name </th>
                                        <th> Model No. </th>
                                        <th> Value </th>
                                        <th> Number of days </th>
                                        <th><center> Status </center></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <?php
                                $con->next_result();
                                $result = mysqli_query($con, "CALL GetToolSpecByStatus(1)");  ?>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

                                    <?php echo "<tr>"; ?>
                                    <?php echo "<td><a href='edit_toolspec.php?ID=".$row['ID']."' style='color:red;'>" . $row['tools_name'] . "</a></td>"; ?>
                                    <?php echo "<td>" . $row['model_num'] . "</td>"; ?>
                                    <?php echo "<td>" . $row['model_num_val'] . "</td>"; ?>
                                    <?php echo "<td>" . $row['no_of_days'] . "</td>"; ?>
                                    <td>
                                        <center>
                                            <p data-id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"
                                                class="status_checks statusButton <?php echo ($row['status'])? 'btn-success': 'btn-danger'?>" >
                                                <?php echo ($row['status'])? 'Active' : 'Inactive'?>
                                            </p>
                                        </center>
                                    </td>
                                    <?php echo "</tr>"; ?>

                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code in Javascript/Jquery

```
    <script>
    $('#dataTables').DataTable();
    </script>
    
    <!-- Need ajax -->
    <script>
    $("#stats").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val() == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive"
        console.log(val)
        $("table tbody tr").hide()
        $("table tr").find(".status_checks:contains(" + val + ")").closest("tr").show()
    })
    
    
    $(document).on('click', '.status_checks', function() {
        var status = '1';
        if ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) {
            status = '0';
        }
        var id = $(this).data('id');
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../forms/form_statusForspecs.php",
            data: {
                id: id,
                status: status
            },
            
            success: function(data) {
                // alert(data);
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
    
    
    </script>
```

Here is the php for AJAX where the the INACTIVE data should be displayed.

```
<?php 

include('../include/connect.php');
    
 
 
$user_id=$_POST['id'];
$newStatus=$_POST['status'];
$query = "UPDATE tools_spec SET status='$newStatus' WHERE ID = '$user_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if($result === TRUE)
    {
        echo json_encode(1);
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(0);
    }
?>
    <?php
    $con->next_result();
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"CALL GetToolSpecByStatus(0)");  ?>

    <tbody>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

        <?php echo '<tr>'; ?>
        <?php echo "<td><a href='edit_toolspec.php?ID=".$row['ID']."' style='color:red;'>" . $row['tools_name'] . "</a></td>"; ?>
        <?php echo "<td>" . $row['model_num'] . "</a></td>"; ?>
        <?php echo "<td>" . $row['model_num_val'] . "</td>"; ?>
        <?php echo "<td>" . $row['no_of_days'] . "</td>"; ?>
        <td>
            <center>
                <p data-id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"
                    class="status_checks statusButton <?php echo ($row['status'])? 'btn-success': 'btn-danger'?>">
                    <?php echo ($row['status'])? 'Active' : 'Inactive'?>
                </p>
            </center>
        </td>
        <?php echo '<tr>'; ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

[Here is the link of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ5fm.png)

Comment: Hi, the problem is with updating data ?

Comment: Hi @Swati yes and no because when I update I lost the data for "INACTIVE", but in the database it is recorded as 0,I used ENUM to define ACTIVE and INACTIVE.

Comment: @Dharman yes sir I am aware of it, I will do this once I finished my problem, this code of mine is for test only. Btw thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `location.reload()` you can change `p` tag class and text inside your success function of ajax . So, if the button has class `btn-success` remove this class using `removeClass()` method and add `btn-danger` class using `addClass()` method and vice-versa.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.status_checks', function() {
  var status = '1';
  var selector = $(this) //declare here
  if (selector.hasClass("btn-success")) {
    status = '0';
  }
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id + "--" + status)
  /* $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../forms/form_statusForspecs.php",
     data: {
       id: id,
       status: status
     },

     success: function(data) {*/
  //check if selector has class success (remove and add class and change text)
  selector.hasClass("btn-success") ? (selector.removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger"), selector.text("Inactive")) : (selector.removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success"), selector.text("Active"))
  /*}
  });*/
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Tools Name </th>
      <th> Model No. </th>
      <th> Value </th>
      <th> Number of days </th>
      <th>
        <center> Status </center>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href='edit_toolspec.php?ID=1' style='color:red;'> something</a></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <p data-id="1" class="status_checks statusButton btn-success">Active
          </p>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href='edit_toolspec.php?ID=2' style='color:red;'> something</a></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <p data-id="2" class="status_checks statusButton btn-danger"> Inactive </p>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><a href='edit_toolspec.php?ID=3' style='color:red;'> something3</a></td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <p data-id="3" class="status_checks statusButton btn-danger"> Inactive </p>
        </center>
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Swati thanks for the answer however I tried this but still not working when I click Inactive. It doesn't show the data in my data table that was updated in my ajax. How should I make the data still shown in inactive whenever I will reload it?

Comment: did you put that code inside success function of ajax ? Also ,remove that ` location.reload();` .

Comment: Yes I did put the code inside success but when I reload the page and click the inactive selector in my datatable, the data is gone but in my SQL the status is correct, the value is 0.

Comment: try to print `$row['status']` what it has ?

Comment: The result is 4 ones and 1 zero because I turned one status of my data inactive. Then when I reload my page the zero is gone.

Comment: `Then when I reload my page the zero is gone..` how can that be possible ? you are not changing anything in your db and your php code is getting data from db :/ . Are you sure correct data are updated ?

Comment: I should make this reference. For the meantime I will try again to find solution. I dunno what is happening inside my code haha. I'll double check what is being sent into my ajax.php. Thanks @Swati

Comment: Try checking if correct value are updating also you don't have any code to update on page reload .. between your code seems ok to me not sure why that behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227318/discussion-between--san-and-swati).